# provious button doesn't work in advanced slider

Tags: javascript, button, slider, carousel

I have found this image carousel but previous button doesn't work. I added id="up_button" and function previousSlide but i don't understand this part with slides[0] etc. I mean I tried to reverse all of those classes and add previous instead next and next instead previous but then there is pure chaos everywhere .it looks like i'm not on that level yet. can anyone figure that out?

```
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="caption" id="slider-caption">
    <div class="caption-heading">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-subhead"><span>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </span></div><a class="btn" href="#">Sit Amet</a>
  </div>
  <div class="left-col" id="left-col">
    <div id="left-slider"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="slide-up"> <a href="#"><</a></li>
    <li class="slide-down"> <a id="down_button" href="#">></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 8rem;
  z-index: 9;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms ease opacity, 500ms ease transform;
  transform: translateY(60px);
}
.caption.current-caption {
  transition-delay: 1000ms;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.caption.previous-caption {
  transform: translateY(-60px);
}
.caption .caption-heading {
  transition: 500ms ease-in all;
}
.caption .caption-heading h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: -0.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.caption .caption-subhead {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  word-spacing: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  display: block;
}
.caption a.btn {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  transition: 250ms ease-in background-color, 500ms ease-in color;
}
.caption a.btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2C302E;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.left-col, .right-col {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100% - 4rem);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-col {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* margin: 2rem; */
  position: relative;
}
.left-col .slide {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(1, 0.04, 0.355, 1) transform, 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) clip-path;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  scale: 1;
  z-index: -1;
}
.left-col .slide.previous {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation-delay: 1s;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  transition: 3s ease transform;
  will-change: transform;
}
.left-col .slide.previous.change {
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
.left-col .slide.next {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
}
.left-col .slide.current {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1.25);
  z-index: 2;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.right-col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right-col .preview {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 6;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav a {
  color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.nav:hover .slide-up, .nav:hover .slide-down {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.nav .slide-up, .nav .slide-down {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease opacity, 0.25s ease transform;
  z-index: 99;
}
.nav .slide-up:hover, .nav .slide-down:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav .slide-up a, .nav .slide-down a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
}
.nav .slide-up {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.nav .slide-down {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```
let slide_data = [
  {
    'src':'../src/img/img1.JPG',
    'title':'',
    'copy':''
  },
  {
    'src':'../src/img/img2.JPG', 
    'title':'',
    'copy':''
  },
  {
    'src':'../src/img/img3.JPG', 
    'title':'',
    'copy':''
  },
  {
    'src':'../src/img/img4.JPG', 
    'title':'',
    'copy':''
  },
  
];
let slides = [],
  captions = [];

let autoplay = setInterval(function(){
  nextSlide();
},5000);
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let leftSlider = document.getElementById('left-col');
// console.log(leftSlider);
let down_button = document.getElementById('down_button');
// let caption = document.getElementById('slider-caption');
// let caption_heading = caption.querySelector('caption-heading');

down_button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  clearInterval(autoplay);
  nextSlide();
  autoplay;
});

for (let i = 0; i< slide_data.length; i++){
  let slide = document.createElement('div'),
      caption = document.createElement('div'),
      slide_title = document.createElement('div');
    
  slide.classList.add('slide');
  slide.setAttribute('style','background:url('+slide_data[i].src+')');
  caption.classList.add('caption');
  slide_title.classList.add('caption-heading');
  slide_title.innerHTML = '<h1>'+slide_data[i].title+'</h1>';
  
  switch(i){
    case 0:
        slide.classList.add('current');
        caption.classList.add('current-caption');
        break;
    case 1:
        slide.classList.add('next');
        caption.classList.add('next-caption');
        break;
    case slide_data.length -1:
      slide.classList.add('previous');
      caption.classList.add('previous-caption');
      break;
    default:
       break;       
  }
  caption.appendChild(slide_title);
  caption.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div class="caption-subhead"><span></span></div>');
  slides.push(slide);
  captions.push(caption);
  leftSlider.appendChild(slide);
  container.appendChild(caption);
}
// console.log(slides);

function nextSlide(){
  // caption.classList.add('offscreen');
  
  slides[0].classList.remove('current');
  slides[0].classList.add('previous','change');
  slides[1].classList.remove('next');
  slides[1].classList.add('current');
  slides[2].classList.add('next');
  let last = slides.length -1;
  slides[last].classList.remove('previous');
  
  captions[0].classList.remove('current-caption');
  captions[0].classList.add('previous-caption','change');
  captions[1].classList.remove('next-caption');
  captions[1].classList.add('current-caption');
  captions[2].classList.add('next-caption');
  let last_caption = captions.length -1;
  
  // console.log(last);
  captions[last].classList.remove('previous-caption');
  
  let placeholder = slides.shift();
  let captions_placeholder = captions.shift();
  slides.push(placeholder); 
  captions.push(captions_placeholder);
}

let heading = document.querySelector('.caption-heading');


// https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/
function whichTransitionEvent(){
  var t,
      el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var transitions = {
    "transition"      : "transitionend",
    "OTransition"     : "oTransitionEnd",
    "MozTransition"   : "transitionend",
    "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
  }

  for (t in transitions){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return transitions[t];
    }
  }
}

var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent()
caption.addEventListener(transitionEvent, customFunction);

function customFunction(event) {
  caption.removeEventListener(transitionEvent, customFunction);
  console.log('animation ended');

  // Do something when the transition ends
}
```